# Is .99999.... equal to 1.00000, or not?

Tags: measure-theory

In history class one of the TA was referring to some kind of mathematic history and mentioned that no one solved .999..... = 1.0000...... which are both never ending decimals. Then someone yelled 'wrong they're equal' but the TA disagreed.

I just want to know who is right totally curious.

Can someone answer this question? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### $\begin{align} x &= 0.999\cdots & (A)\\ 10x &= 9.999\cdots & (B)\\ 9x &= 9.000\cdots & (B-A)\\ \therefore x &= 1.000\cdots \end{align}$

Comment: how did you get B?

Comment: I see it now. crystal clear

Comment: Simply multiply $A$ by $10$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are equal.  Proof:
$$1/3 = 0.333....$$
Then multiply both sides by 3.

Comment: if you multiply both sides you get 1 = 1?

Comment: On the left, you get 1.  On the right, you get 0.9999.....

Comment: i don't get it .... when you multiply 1/3 by 3 you get 1 which is 1.0000

Comment: Exactly.  You wanted to know if 1.000.... = 0.9999...., and that's what you got.  On the left side, $3 \times (1/3) = 1.000....$.  On the right side you get 0.9999.....

Comment: oh i didn't think of it that way, my bad i must be stupid thanks though